# Code completion for Eigen library doesn’t seem to fully work

Tags: qt, eigen

I just started using Eigen 3.2.0 on QTCreator 2.8.1. 
All is well but code completion only seems to partially work – I get a bunch of options, but many are missing. Here’s a screenshot of an uber simple code snippet – as you’ll see, the list of available functions for m0 is limited (e.g. block() and col() are missing but cols() is there).

[image]

However, all of these functions seem to be usable – the code compiles and runs properly. This is a problem, given that Eigen has a lot of functionalities, and I’m nowhere close to remembering the name for all of them. I tried a bunch of random things, but am not quite sure what’s going on. Here’s the code from my .pro project file, in case

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = LearnEigen
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += ..\..\Libs\Eigen
```

Would be forever thankful for any advice or pointers to other threads that may have addressed this.
thank you!

Comment: I think it's just a limitation of the IDE.  I've had to deal with the same thing --- it's pretty complex stuff.  You might want to give [CDT (Eclipse)](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) a shot... as it has some pretty heavy duty indexing that leads to superior auto-completion.

Comment: Eigen makes extensive use of CRTP which the code-completer struggles with.  There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I assume you mean "you can't don anything about in QT"? I think Visual Studio deals with it just fine  - I guess I should consider porting?

Answer (score 1):

Long time since your question, but for anyone may want this problem to be solved, take a shot to the following option:

Go to **Help**-> **About Plugins**... -> enable **ClangCodeModel**
Restart Qt Creator. Check that it got activated; Tools -> C++ -> Code Model

problem solved!.